# Memory leak in vector of pointers, how to prevent?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, vector, memory-leaks

I'm getting a bit of a memory leak in my program and this is about the only thing I think it could be.

```
if (inputType == 'S')
{
    SavingAccount* savingAccount = new SavingAccount();
    inFile >> *savingAccount;

    accounts.push_back(savingAccount);
}
```

While the vector of pointers is deleted at the end of the program, I am having 3 error leaks which seem to correspond with the 3 types of accounts I have. That being said, if I delete the pointer after putting it into the vector, it deletes the entry in the vector as well (which I expected)

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

EDIT:

```
void Transaction::cleanUp()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++)
    {
        delete accounts[i];
    }

    accounts.clear();
}
```

clean up code added.

EDIT: RESOLVED

My issue didn't have as much to do with the vector as it did the destructors of the classes. As I had not defined a virtual destructor only the base class was being erased, leaving behind fragments of the derived classes. There is no no memory leak after adding this.

Comment: Can you post your cleanup code?

Comment: You wrote `this is about the only thing I think it could be` - why do you think that this could be the only cause? Before looking at your vector more closely, consider other places using `new` and `malloc`.

Comment: I don't use malloc anywhere, anywhere else with "new" has a delete after it, everywhere except for here.

Comment: Btw, the reason the vector doesn't delete the pointers for you, is that if it did then you wouldn't be able to store pointers that *weren't* allocated with `new`, or that you didn't want deleted when the vector was destroyed.

Comment: You have mentioned that you have a base class. Does this base class have a virtual destructor?

Answer (score 8):

Why do you need pointers in your vector?  I haven't seen much of your code, but AFAIK this below could work just as well, if your `SavingAccount` class is copy constructible:

```
if (inputType == 'S')
    {
        SavingAccount savingAccount;
        inFile >> savingAccount;

        accounts.push_back(savingAccount); //puts a copy in the vector, so your class needs a copy ctor + Rule of Three applied.
    }
```

**EDIT**

Seeing OP says he has a polymorphic class structure, then OP should use a `std::unique_ptr` and store that in the `std::vector` or consider using `boost::ptr_vector` which is designed for storing pointers.

Comment: The program uses derived classes, storing the derived class into the vector will make it lose that information, thus the need for pointers.

Comment: Slight variation (may be more efficient): `accounts.push_back(SavingAccount()); inFile >> accounts.back(); `

Comment: @user1623990 you should use `std::unique_ptr` then, and store that in your `std::vector` or use the `boost::vector_ptr`

Comment: inFile >> accounts.back() doesn't compile?

Comment: Doesn't scale well.  The larger the classes, the longer it takes to copy them, (if it's even possible/safe).  If the vector access needs a lock, moving pointers in/out is much faster than copying whole objects and so reduces the chance of contention.  Any copying also implies that, at least temporarily, the data is in more than one place - not a good idea in general.

Comment: @MartinJames I can see the point you're trying to make, but OP hasn't mentioned anything about threading. This does not apply here.

Comment: @TonyTheLion - refactoring an app to accommodate multithreading, (and the inter-thread comms that goes with it), is very difficult and awkward if it's already riddled with stack-based objects and copy-ctors.  IMHO, it's better to consider such things from the start, especially if you want your classes to be re-useable.  Also, I don't think that anyone actually likes writing copy-ctors if they can avoid it:)

Comment: @MartinJames are you advocating the use of pointers? Do you realize that brings other unnecessary complexities with it?

Comment: @MartinJames: Since the stack isn't shared between threads, stack-based objects need no locking, and thus make threading easier. Besides that, they are _easier_ to deal with even in single-threaded code, and should thus be t he default.

Comment: @sbi - Niether stack or heap-based objects need any locking if they are not shared, but heap objects can be safely and easily be communicated by pointer, (or shared_ptr, or auto-ptr, or whatever_ptr), to other threads.  As for easier to use on single-threaded code, yes, absolutely agree there.  OTOH, of the 70 processes running on my box now, only two are single-threaded.  Do you want you classes/units to be easily re-useable in an efficient manner on all projects?

Comment: @user1623990 - oh yes, I realize that.  I'm sure that your app is single-threaded, (today:).

Comment: @TonyTheLion - yes, I have a grasp of the complexities associated with using pointers and, in the OP code, today, you make a good case for avoiding them they are inded strictly unnecessary, today, in this app, with no case ever for threading through this code/data in this app, or others, and never needing to communicate an account to another thread.  Sure, there are extra complexities with pointers, the upside is that, without them, it's 'extremely difficult' to develop many multithreaded, high-performance, reliable apps - any app that needs to move large objects around.

Comment: @MartinJames: "heap objects can be safely and easily be communicated by pointer" ___What?___

Comment: @sbi 'stack-based objects make threading easier' - missed that one.  To accept that places a heavy burden upon the logical and semantic resources of the English language, (I disagree:).

Comment: @MartinJames: I can't help but have to assume you're trolling now. _HAND._

Comment: @sbi OK, your network connection generates 10MB of network-buffers per second.  The buffers need to be queued to a threadpool that will parse/process them into video buffers.  The buffers then need to be communicated to a GUI thread that will render them on-screen. How would you suggest that is done efficently, safely and easily so that no two threads are ever operating on the same object? Pointers OK, shared_ptr OK, copying .. not so much, really:)

Comment: @sbi Despite that near-insulting remark, I will manage to refrain from shouting.  I am not trolling now, nor have I ever done so.  This is going to be my last post on this thread - I have no wish to involve myself any further with an exchange that is going south re. civility and the normal pleasant tone of this group.

Answer (score 3):

Either use an `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr<SavingAccount>` or loop over the vector, deleting all elements before the vector goes out of scope or gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can either delete before destroying the vector or store smart pointers in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `SavingAccount*`, stored in you vector, before the destroying of the vector.

Or use smart pointers, if you can.